# Computer won't display image on one particular TV

Tags: display, hdmi, tv

So after building a new computer for myself, I gave my old one to my roommate, but for some reason it will not display anything on startup when connected to his TV. The tricky part is that I've already ruled out all the obvious stuff:

Graphics card - Plugging into the port for the integrated graphics does not fix the issue.

Computer - Computer displays image with no issues on other TV/monitor.

TV HDMI ports - Plugging into a port known to function does not fix the issue.

HDMI cable - Switching to a second HDMI cable known to function does not fix the issue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Solved, see below

Comment: plug a monitor into the PC and change the resolution to something smaller 800x600 or 1024x768 before plugging into the HDMI tv, it could be that the TV is unable to accept the resolution the pc is trying to output.

Answer (score 0):

'Maybe the GPU requires a certain HDMI version (like 1.4) but the TV does not support it. However all versions should be backward compatible with older variants but maybe the TV has a faulty HDMI implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, although I admittedly still don't fully understand it. The answer I was given was that some older HDMI-capable TVs can be picky about how input is received, so in order for the TV to accept the computer's input, the computer must be allowed to fully boot up while the TV is still off. Turning on the TV after the boot sequence had finished allowed it to work.